# la funcion .push() de javascript no agrega elementos sino que cambia un unico elemento del array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

he estado haciendo una app de lista de tareas con react para lo cual necesito agregar elementos al final de un array pero cuando utilizo la funcion .push() lo que pasa es que se agrega un unico elemento al array y este mismo elemento cambia por los valores que le paso a la funcion en vez de estos valores agregarse al final.

a continuacion la funcion y como declaro el arreglo

```
 let notes = []
  const [showNotes, setShowNotes] = useState([])

  function addNote(){
    notes.push( newListName.value )
    setShowNotes(notes)
    newListName.value = ''
    console.log(notes)
  }
```

tambien dejo por aqui el codigo de como recorro el array para enseñar las distintas listas de notas ya que es primera vez que utilizo la funcion .map() por si cometi algun error en esta

```
{showNotes.map((note) => 
    <Box sx={{ 
        borderRadius:'10px',
        borderColor:'white',
        borderStyle:'solid',
        width:'10rem',
        textAlign:'center'
        }}
    >
        {note}
    </Box>)
}
```

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda y muchisimas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `push` está funcionando correctamente, lo que sucede es que la estás usando de forma incorrecta.

**PROBLEMA**

Se tiene un estado inicial que es un Array llamado `showNotes`, que debe actualizarse mediante alguna acción, sin embargo al actualizar el estado de este Array con `setShowNotes`, el mismo no se actualiza correctamente y sólo contiene el último elemento añadido a un Array llamado `notes`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, pero vamos a explicar primero el porqué está ocurriendo esto.

Tienes un componente y un estado llamado `showNotes`, el cual estás estableciendo como un Array vacío, también tienes un Array llamado `notes` que también inicializas como un Array vacío:

```js
let notes = [];
const [ showNotes, setShowNotes ] = useState([]);
```

Al momento de llamar a la acción, en tu función `addNote`, actualizas el estado, haciendo:

```js
notes.push( newListName.value );
setShowNotes(notes);
```

En esta acción, estás añadiendo un elemento al Array `notes` y luego estás actualizando el estado de `showNotes`, estableciendo el valor del mismo, al valor de `notes`. Pero esto provoca un renderizado del componente, por lo cual, el valor del Array `notes` es nuevamente incializado a un Array vacío.

El estado (`showNotes`) se mantiene, porque eso es el comportamiento esperado del estado en React, y contendrá el elemento que has añadido anteriormente, pero si añades otro elemento, el `push` lo estás aplicando sobre `notes` (que está vacío) y luego estableces el estado de `showNotes` a lo que contiene `notes`. Por lo tanto, el estado anterior (que contenía el primer elemento) es sobreescrito con el nuevo valor de `notes`, que contiene sólo un elemento (el que acabas de añadir).

Para evitar esto, tienes (al menos) 2 opciones:

1. No usar un Array `notes` y actualizar directamente el estado
2. Usar el Array `notes` pero añadiendo al mismo cualquier elemento de estados anteriores.

Yo me decantaría por la primera opción, actualizando directamente el estado y sin usar ningún Array adicional, más que el mismo estado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const [ showNotes, setShowNotes ] = useState([]);  // estado se inicializa vacío
function addNote(){
    setShowNotes([...showNotes, newListName.value]);
    newListName.value = '';
}
```

En este caso, no estoy [mutando](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-objects-and-arrays-in-state) el estado de `showNotes` usando `push` ([usar `push` muta el Array](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#adding-to-an-array)), sino que estoy estableciendo su valor a un nuevo Array que contiene todo lo que contiene para ese momento `showNotes` (usando la [sintaxis *spread*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) y añadiendo luego el nuevo elemento.

De esta forma, el nuevo estado contendrá los elementos que vas añadiendo y no sólo el último elemento.

Si quisieras usar por algún motivo el Array llamado `notes` (cosa que veo innecesaria de momento), la lógica sería la misma, pero en esta caso, si podrías usar `push`, ya que `notes` no guarda ningún estado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const notes = [];
const [ showNotes, setShowNotes ] = useState([]);

function addNote(){
    notes.push( ...showNotes, newListName.value );
    setShowNotes(notes);
    newListName.value = '';
    console.log(notes);
}
```

En este caso, estoy usando `push` para añadir todo lo que contenga `showNotes` y el nuevo valor (`newListName.value`) al Array `notes`, luego actualizo el estado asignando como nuevo estado el contenido de `notes`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola, si pude solucionar con tu ayuda, no conocia la sintaxis spread, muchas gracias